# BoundField' object is not iterable - Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

forms.py

```
Date_Format = (
    ('0', ' dd / mm / yyyy'),
    ('1', 'mm / dd / yyyy'),
)    
Time_Format = (
    ('0', ' 12 hour AM / PM '),
    ('1', ' 24 hour '),
)
class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_format = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=Date_Format)
    time_format = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=Time_Format)
```

template.py

```
{% for radio in SettingsForm.date_format %}
 {{ radio.choice_label }}
 <div class="select">{{ radio.tag }}</div>
 {% endfor %}
```

traceback

```
Template error:
In template /root/Projects/ir/templates/incident/date_format.html, error at line 107
   Caught TypeError while rendering: 'BoundField' object is not iterable
   97 :                 <tr>
   98 :                     <td style="width:200px;">
   99 : 
   100 :                         {{ SettingsForm.date_format }}
   101 :                         {% for radio in form.date_format %}
   102 :                         
   103 :                         <div >{{ radio }}</div>
   104 :                         {% endfor %}
   105 :                     </td>
   106 :                     <td>eg 21 / 01 / 2014 <br /> 
   107 :        {% for date in SettingsForm.time_format %} 
   108 :         {{ date.label_tag }}
   109 :         {{ date }}
   110 :       {% endfor %} 
   113 :                 </tr>
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/root/Projects/ir/incident/views.py" in date_format
  796.                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  188.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  123.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  64.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  190.             values = list(values)

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /member/date-format/
Exception Value: Caught TypeError while rendering: 'BoundField' object is not iterable
```

I am using django 1.3.7.

Since radio button is rendered in unorderded list,i used radio button customization.

I am getting this error,while customizing the radio buttons.

**Update:**

Normally if i render a radio choice button,will render in  list in page.If i want it to be displayed without that list format i.e without bullet point.How to do using css or any other techniques

Thanks

Comment: Please try changing the line `{% for radio in SettingsForm.date_format %}` to `{% for radio in SettingsForm.date_format.field.choices %}`

Comment: error was solved,but the radio choice button is rendered in list,i want it to be in without list

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by that. Can you edit your question to explain?

Comment: I'm still not clear about the question- in particular, I don't understand what your HTML output looks like. However, this doesn't have anything to do with your initial question, so I suggest you create a new one. It would be a good idea to show the generated HTML and explain why it doesn't look like what you want it to (For one thing, I'm not sure whether your code is `<div>` or `<div class="select">`- it differs between your code and your error traceback). In the meantime, I added the answer to your original question as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
{% for radio in SettingsForm.date_format %}
```

to

```
{% for radio in SettingsForm.date_format.field.choices %}
```